# In how many ways can two dozen identical robots be assigned to four assembly lines?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> In how many ways can two dozen identical robots be  assigned to four
>   assembly lines with
>
> (a) at least three robots  assigned to each line?
>
> (b) at least three, but no more than nine assigned to each line ?

Two dozen = 24,

Now we use generating functions so for (a) we would have $(x^3+x^4+.........)^4$ but we can take $x^{12}$ as a common factor so we have $(x^3+x^4+.........)^4 = x^{12}(1+x + x^2 + ........)^4$ and we already know that $\frac{1}{1-x} = (1+x+x^2+......)$ and so $\frac{1}{(1-x)^4} = (1+x+x^2+.......)^4$

and so we have  $x^{12}(1+x + x^2 + ........)^4 = x^{12}(1-x)^{-4}$. Now want to find the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in $(1-x)^{-4}$  which is ${-4 \choose 12} = (-1)^{12} {4 + 12 -1 \choose 12} = {15 \choose 12}$

Now for (b) I get stuck.

First we have $(x^3 + x^4 + ........ +x^9)^4$, now again we take $x^{12}$ as a common factor and so we have $x^{12}(1 + x + x^2 + .... + x^6)^4$ , and now I want to find the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in $(1 + x + x^2 + .... + x^6)^4$, But how do we do this ?

Comment: Maybe use the fact that your expression is $(1-x^7)^4(1-x)^{-4}$.

Comment: why is that so ?? @AndréNicolas

Comment: Sum of a finite geometric progression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: We have, by the usual formula for the sum of a finite geometric progression, that if $x\ne 0$ then
$$1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^6=\frac{1-x^7}{1-x}.$$
It follows that
$$(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^6)^4=(1-x^7)^4(1-x)^{-4}.$$
Note that we only need two easy terms of the expansion of $(1-x^7)^4$.